# Poor Performance with multiple UICollectionViewCells in one CollectionVIew

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView with multiple cell types. When scrolling between different cell types performance can get **very** laggy. I'm not exactly sure how to fix it. Here's my `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

if cellType == "imageCell" {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("iCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCell

            //do things for cell

            return cell

        }else if cellType == "mapCell" {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("mCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MapCollectionViewCell

            //do things for cell

            return cell

        }else if cellType == "pCell" {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("pCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PCell

            //do things for cell

            return cell

        }else if cellType == "detailCell" {

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("fCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DetailCell

            //do things for cell

            return cell

        }else{
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }}
```

Comment: Is that it? Any setup code in cell's awakeFromNib? What do cells contain?

Comment: If you run exactly the code you posted (i.e. do nothing to any of the cells), is it still slow?

Comment: @Mercurial It's either just an image with a label, a scrollview with a textVIew and an image, or a scrollview with a mapview

Comment: Where do the images come from ?

Comment: @PhillipMills with not setting any of the data for the cell it's still slightly sluggish, but no where near as bad as it is while the data is being set.

Comment: @BoilingLime all stored in `imagexcassetes`. Nothing is being downloaded.

Comment: your code is exactly `//do things for cell` ? or you removed it for posting in SO ?

Comment: @ryancrunchi I removed it for SO. I can put it back, but it's just a lot of basic stuff, like `cell.imageView.image = SomeImage`. Etc.

Comment: ok, do you implement other delegate's methods like `- collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: @ryancrunchi I didnt, should I? (I'm kinda new to UICollectionVIew, so I'm not really sure)

Comment: No it's ok. Try to run the app by profiling it with Instruments and "Time profiler" and see which method takes a lot of time to perform while scrolling.

Comment: @ryancrunchi all i see is that the main thread is taking the most time - then theres a bunch of sub-lists, but they go pretty far deep. Is there anything I should specifically be looking for?

Comment: In Instruments check `Hide system libraries` to reduce the call stack. And expand the main thread sublist to find a method that seems familiar to you.

Comment: @ryancrunchi so it seems like the biggest culprit is the cell that contains an MKMapVIew. But cells that contain a scrollView or multiple imageVIews also seem to take up a good amount of time. Not sure exactly ho to solve that...

Comment: MKMapView requires a lot of resources and can take a while to load. Take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339210/show-mkmapview-in-uitableviewcell-without-slow-down-ui). For images, how big are they ?

Comment: @ryancrunchi gonna take a look at the link. The images themselves, or the imageViews? Thanks a ton for your help, you don't know how much I appreciate this :)

Comment: No problem :). What are the images size (width x height) and their weight ? Also how many images are you displaying in one cell ?

Comment: @ryancrunchi the images vary in size  - I'm assuming they probably need to be scaled down. Theres a maximum of 4 images being displayed in a cell.

Comment: If images are very big ( > 2Mb) try to load them asynchronously or modify them to be smaller to fit the size of your UI. Don't forget `@2x` and/or `@3x` scales :)

Comment: @ryancrunchi Just checked almost all of them are 1.5MB +. Is there any way to dynamically scale them down for `@2x` & `@3x`?

Comment: forget resizing for now and try `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL), ^{
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blabla"];       
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [imageView setImage:image];
    });
});`

Comment: @ryancrunchi it didn't really fix the lagginess, but I think it has to do with the size of the image, they're almost all over 2.5mb

Comment: If your images are large you should consider caching or generating thumbnails.